# Punctuation in verb + but + verb + and + verb structure

Tags: punctuation

In a sentence

> A homophone has the same pronunciation as another word but differs in
>   meaning and may differ in spelling.

is comma before *and* mandatory or optional?

P.S. Perhaps different style guides have different rules for this situation. Please let me know which one you go by when giving your answer (at least, if it's British or North American).

Comment: A comma after? Do you mean before, such as an Oxford comma?

Comment: @Julia Yes, of course. I meant to write "before." Thank you for spotting it.

Comment: I think Elements of Style would tell you to put a comma before "but."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Chicago Manual of Style (16th Edition):

> "A comma is not normally used between the parts of a compound predicate - that is, two or more verbs having the same subject, as distinct from two independent clauses. A comma may occasionally be needed, however, to prevent a misreading."

This means that, since all of the verbs have the same subject, you would not use a comma. (If any of them had a different subject, then you would need a comma before the coordinating conjunction.)

Comment: I'd add that a comma is not forbidden, and may also have a sensible use in enhancing readibility. "A homophone has the same pronunciation as one or more other words in the lexicon, but – being a different word – differs in meaning and etymology, and may differ in spelling."

Answer (score 0):

A comma after *and* is neither mandatory nor optional. It is wrong. In addition to not making any sense whatsoever. You will not find any style guide that greenlights it.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I meant to write "before." I apologize.